# Date Range Picker how to fire an event on entering a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using Dan Grossman's daterangepicker.

http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/

Which is initialised in my web page, and now I'm trying to write the javascript that will be implemented once the date is entered by the user.  However I have run into difficulty getting the daterangepicker to fire an event.

The code I'm using is

```
$('#dateRange').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    alert(ev);
});
```

And here is the code that initialises the daterangepicker

```
$('#dateRange').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
    },
    startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
    endDate: moment()
},
function(start, end) {
    $('#dateRange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
});
```

I've tried lots of different ways to listen for the event like `on.('blur')` or `on.('enter')` but nothing is firing the event for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this section is the callback function:

```
function(start, end) {
    $('#dateRange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
}
```

you can add any code you want in this function to execute when a user selects a date. you could even define a callback function yourself and pass it to the daterange picker method.

example:

```
function myCallback(start, end) {
    $('#dateRange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    alert('hello world'); //etc, your code here
}
// attach daterangepicker plugin
$('#dateRange').daterangepicker(options, myCallback);
```

you also could even define your own custom event handler and trigger it in the callback as well.

example

```
$(document).on('myCustomEvent', function () {
    // your code here
});

$('#dateRange').daterangepicker({
// .. //
function(start, end) {
    $('#dateRange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    $(document).trigger('myCustomEvent');
});
```

Comment: I am using cakephp and same daterange picker for my project, how i can send start and end date to Controller using this myCustonevetnt?

Comment: @Neil S, I am facing one issue when I don't change the default selected value in the daterangepicker, when clicking on apply button the callback function is not executed. Is there any solution to that.

Comment: How to call daterangepicker method .hide on mouseleave event from outside container. I added another thread for the same.  @tejashsoni111

Comment: @AakashKumar I think you should post a new question with some of your code and explain your issue there so everyone can suggest you solution.

Comment: @tejashsoni111 It got resolved with my latest asked question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142215/to-close-daterangepicker-on-mouseleave-event

Answer (score 21):

From daterangepicker.com:

```
$('#daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    alert ('hello');
});
```