# Detect change from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text input which has its content changed via javascript. However, the onchange event doesn't seems to capture this change. Is there a way to detect when an input is changed via Javascript?

Comment: please add the code which changes the input.

Comment: It's a dateRangePicker which doesn't support a callback.

Comment: Please specify, usually plugins can support such things.

Comment: http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/

Comment: There is a paragraph which specifes the callback. it is named "Pre-defined Ranges & Callback Example"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JQuery so that you can do

```
$('element').on('input', function () {
   alert(this.value);
});
```

Otherwise, with JavaScript alone use `onkeyup="alert(this.value);"`

If it is for a datePicker, then you probably can use its `onSelect` event.

This answer adds an event for the plugin you specified in the comments [Date Range Picker how to fire an event on entering a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562616/date-range-picker-how-to-fire-an-event-on-entering-a-date)

============================ Quote Start ================================

```
function myCallBack(start, end) {
    $('#dateRange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    alert('hello world'); //etc, your code here
}
// attach daterangepicker plugin
$('#dateRange').daterangepicker(options, myCallback);
```

you also could even define your own custom event handler and trigger it in the callback as well.

example

```
$(document).on('myCustomEvent', function () {
    // your code here
});

$('#dateRange').daterangepicker({
// .. //
function(start, end) {
    $('#dateRange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    $(document).trigger('myCustomEvent');
});
```

============================ Quote End ================================

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track changes as you type, use `onkeydown`. If you need to trap paste operations with the mouse, use `onpaste` (IE, FF3) and `oninput` (FF, Opera, Chrome, Safari1).

Comment: The content is changed by a dateRangePicker which doesn't support  callback. I tried oninput and onpaste but they don't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using HTML5, you can use the `input` event

```
document.getElementById("textinput").addEventListener("input", function(e){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have changed the inputs value you can call `onchange()` on the input to trigger the onchange event

```
document.getElementById('myInput').onchange();
```

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding to our conversation in comments.

Here is the Link to your DateRangePicker plugin [On Github](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker)

There is a paragraph which expains the using on callbacks....

### Quote From the Link

> The constructor also takes an optional options object and callback
> function. The function will be called whenever the selected date range
> has been changed by the user, and is passed the start and end dates
> (moment date objects) as parameters.

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker(
  { 
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    startDate: '2013-01-01',
    endDate: '2013-12-31'
  },
  function(start, end) {
    alert('A date range was chosen: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can capture the changes that are occuring.

Try this:

```
var something = ""; // create variable..
$('input').keyup(function () { // on a key up..
   something = $(this).val(); // update the variable..
}
```

Otherwise, you can simply use `.replace(value, '')` to remove the previous words and just write the newly written words in the variable.

To detect the change, you need to save the initial state, and then match it with the final state. To save the initial state you need to create a variable at the page load. And then after the time, you can compare both and remove the initial words and continue.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question... Using javascript (because jquery et al is not javascript, its programmed in javascript)

```
Object.addEventListener("change",yourFunc );
```

where Object is the object you want to listen to, this can be the document, an element, depending on what you want to detect.