# DatePicker in Laravel not listening for event handle (onChange)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with this [Date Range Picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples), I have a `<div>`. `onclick` of the button datepicker pop up appears and user selects a date from the calender pop up and the selected date is populated in the text field.

I want to print the chosen dates value (From - To) by JS alert statement. I already tried many suggestions, nut still not working.

I tried most of the solutions on Google but still no one can give me the right answer.

HTML Code:

```
<input  id="#return" name="start" class="date-pick form-control" value="" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" />
<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>
```

And the jQuery as following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var start = moment().subtract(2, 'days');
        var end = moment();

        function cb(start, end) {
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        }

        $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, cb);

        cb(start, end);
        alert(start.format('YYYY-M-DD hh:mm:ss') + end.format('YYYY-M-DD hh:mm:ss'));
```

It already printed the picked dates on first load of the page, then no more results again, except if I load the page again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Range Picker how to fire an event on entering a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562616/date-range-picker-how-to-fire-an-event-on-entering-a-date)

Comment: What is `Predefined Date Range: Date Range Picker`? Your question is tagged with `JQueryUI datepicker`, but the code does not look like that. If you are using a particular library, please make that clear, maybe add a link to it, don't assume everyone knows what it is.  And if it is not jQueryUI's Datepicker, please remove that tag.  It will be easier for people to help you if they can work out what your question is about.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - that's not the jQueryUI Datepicker, so I removed that tag.