# To close daterangepicker on mouseleave event

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I am using the daterangepicker library in my application. I want to trigger daterangepicker's internal method .hide() once use leaves daterangepicker container area. My code looks like this.

```
<body class="visual-sandbox">
   <div class="visual-rangepicker">
      <div id="reportrange" class="report-range">
          <div class="calendar-icon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>
          </div>&nbsp;
          <span></span> <b class="caret caret-dropdown"></b>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>

$("#reportrange").daterangepicker(
        {
          startDate: start,
          endDate: end,
          opens: 'left',
          ranges: {
            // new Date(2017, 11, 1)
            Today: [moment(new Date()), moment(new Date())],
            Yesterday: [
              moment(new Date()).subtract(1, "days"),
              moment(new Date()).subtract(1, "days")
            ],
            "Last 7 Days": [moment(new Date()).subtract(6, "days"), moment(new Date())],
            "Last 30 Days": [moment(new Date()).subtract(29, "days"), moment(new Date())],
            "This Month": [moment(new Date()).startOf("month"), moment(new Date()).endOf("month")],
            "Last Month": [
              moment(new Date())
                .subtract(1, "month")
                .startOf("month"),
              moment(new Date())
                .subtract(1, "month")
                .endOf("month")
            ],
            "Last Year": [
              moment(new Date())
                .subtract(1, "year")
                .startOf("year"),
              moment(new Date())
                .subtract(1, "year")
                .endOf("year"),
            ]
          }
        },
        cb
      ).on;
      cb(start, end);
```

Now let's say #reportrange containing area is body tag. I want to apply something like this function and close the current open daterangepicker.

```
$('body').on('mouseleave', function(){
      $('#reportrange').trigger('hide.daterangepicker'); //it doesn't work.
    });
```

A simple solution like.

```
$('body').on('mouseleave', function(){
      $('#reportrange').hide();
    });
```

works and hides that particular area but user have to click twice to open that daterangepicker again. As fist click is again closing picker ( toggle ) and second click is opening it.

To understand it properly, if you go to this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rg7fh1a8/ 
Now if the user hovers outside area of it, I want to close this daterangepicker.

Comment: You try `trigger`ing `click` on the cancel button?

Comment: No. I need to call it by default once the user leaves the containing area with the mouse.

Comment: Right.  Instead of calling `hide()`, call `trigger()` on the click button which should also hide the dialog but eliminate the need to click twice.

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet? I tried trigger too but not getting how to call daterangepicker internal method. Currently, above-mentioned methods point to jQuery instead of daterangepicker. I know it has to do something using the correct way of passing references.

Comment: You would need to provide an [mcve].  I don't have your HTML or what scripts you're including.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I don't have much HTML. It is quite simple. Though I updated the question.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Hi, I also added the JSFiddle link and description in the original answer.

Comment: Aakash, no offense but I don't have the time or desire to pull your code apart in order to create a reproduction of your issue.  If you turned it into a working snippet it would probably be easy (i.e.  an [mcve], which I've already asked for).  Links to external sites in languages I don't speak aren't worth a lot.

Comment: @Tibrogargan shared jsfiddle is in English also. Please refer to the second last one.

Comment: Aakash.  The code you posted **does not run**.  I am not going to spend the effort required to reproduce the issue then create a solution when apparently you won't even go to the effort to post the list of scripts you use in your question.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I updated my question with working JSfiddle. And mentioning URL here also. https://jsfiddle.net/rg7fh1a8/

Comment: You should not be using off-site resources in your questions.  They can disappear without warning which ruins your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know there's already an accepted answer, but I think this could also be useful because it's using the daterangepicker's native hide function instead of simulating a click on cancel button:

```
$(function(){
    $('.daterangepicker').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to be a more correct approach I  believe.

Comment: @AakashKumar It's actually not a good idea, since the click handler does more than just a `hide()`.  It also modifies some internal variables and fires the `cancel.daterangepicker` event.  You might be able to call `clickCancel` on the daterangepicker, but it may not be exported.  That would be a better solution, except it would then give you a hard dependency on the internal implementation of a 3rd party solution - which is not a good idea.

Comment: Since this is the way you should call the daterangepicker object's methods according to the documentation, I don't think the hard dependency will be a problem because any changes to the implementation should be mentioned in the docs if the authors change the code. And the `hide()` method is used so often in the code that I can't think of any reason for renaming it or completely changing its functionality.

Comment: If you were calling a `hide` that daterangepicker exposes i would agree, but you're calling JQuery's `hide`

Comment: Nope. Placing an alert inside daterangepicker's internal `hide` function shows me that it's not jQuery's `hide` I'm calling. I can also use `clickCancel()` on mouseleave (which surely isn't a jQuery function, but defined in the daterangepicker code) instead of `hide()`, and it's working.

Comment: Yep. Put a breakpoint in daterangepicker's `hide` and you will see it's being called from jQuery, because jQuery is smart enough to check that the target implements it.  Your answer would be better if you called `clickCancel` as you're skipping part of the implementation.... which puts you back in the situation of calling a method that is not documented.

Comment: Using my code from above with a named function instead of an anonymous function and a breakpoint at the start of daterangepicker's `hide()` function, the call stack is showing: `hide`, `myDRPhider` and a subsection `jQuery` below. Which tells me that the the method `hide` was called by `myDRPhider`, which used jQuery code when executed. If the method was called by jQuery, the second line in the call stack would be jQuery, not the function I defined.

Comment: My bad, not paying attention to the use of `data` as documented by daterangepicker.  Still not comfortable with this usage as it doesn't resolve the issue of relying on undocumented features.  Sure, the authors say it provides access to the methods and properties of the underlying object ... but this is the internet, things change.  Also not really comfortable with my solution using undocumented classes.

Comment: It's rather "lazy-documented" than undocumented. But I agree, it's nothing you can rely on in future versions without taking a closer look at the source code or the DOM object first.

Answer (score 3):

This solution finds the cancel button in the daterangepicker and clicks it programmatically.  It assumes that the daterangepicker library is using the default classes that the current release assigns to it's controls.  These class names were found by examining the elements of the daterangepicker in the rendered HTML using chrome dev tools.

Avoid putting `onmouseleave` on the body itself (unless you're using `on` with a selector).  I've attached it to the class in this example.

```js
$(function() {
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker();
});

function init() {
$('.daterangepicker').on("mouseleave", function() { $(this).find('.cancelBtn').click() });
}

$(init);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
   <div class="visual-rangepicker">
      <input id="reportrange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015">
   </div>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Why I am feeling so stupid. I know jQuery but I did not get this simple solution in mind. Thanks a lot. @Tibrogargan

Answer (score 0):

How to implement close using a click event externally

```
$('--DIV ID--').data('daterangepicker').hide();

$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').hide();  // change to hidden state
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker();  // change to hidden state AND reset options

ex) <button onclick="$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').hide();">Close Test</button>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

In Date Range Picker Available `hide.daterangepicker` Event. Go to http://www.daterangepicker.com/#events, Check hide event.

Comment: The `hide.daterangepicker` event is fired when the `hide()` method is called.  It is not called when the mouse leaves the daterangepicker

Comment: I tried this solution only which did not work for me.