# two datepicker and both are connected with each other you select date of one and another one automatically selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two datepickers (calendar), both are connected with each other. When I select a date from one, another datepicker date should be automatically selected.

I am trying with javascript but that is not working. I am failing to do this

```
$(function () {
    $('#example1').daterangepicker({
        showCalendar: true,
        locale: { format: 'DD-MMMM-YYYY' },
        autoApply: true,
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#example2').daterangepicker({
            showCalendar: true,
            locale: { format: 'DD-MMMM-YYYY' },
            autoApply: true,
        });
```

the date will be shown one selected from anyone

Comment: so what you want?

Comment: i want, when i select date from one datepicker then date will also select from second date picker

Comment: See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18562809/6018222) answer and write some code inside that function that sets the value of the other one to the value of the first one.

Comment: you can set the value of the second date picker when the first one is selected. use the value of first one and set it on the second.

Comment: how can i am set values ?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input id="from"> <input id="to">
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
  $('#to').datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(dateStr)
    {
      $("#to").datepicker( "hide" );
      $('#from').val(dateStr);
      $('#from').focus();

      $('#from').datepicker( "show" );
      $("#from").datepicker( "option", "minDate", finalDate );
    }
  });

  $("#from").datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function(dateStr)
    {
      $("#from").datepicker( "hide" );
      $('#to').val(dateStr);
      $('#to').focus();

      $('#to').datepicker( "show" );
      $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", finalDate );
    }
  });
</script>
```

See the below jsfiddle:

[Datepicker](https://jsfiddle.net/pathik2012/fsz0gtua/)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this way.

```
$('#example1').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#example2').val(value);
});
```

If you want this to work for any one add the following as well

```
$('#example2').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#example1').val(value);
});
```